# Laravel: Getting data from my pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've just started using Laravel and I am really enjoying it. I am a little confused about how to access data at times and i'm not sure if I am going around this in the right way, Maybe somebody can help?
I want to simply output the Club Name and Opponent Club Name in a loop of Fixtures.
I have the following tables:

```
// a clubs table
Schema::create('clubs', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 20);
    $table->string('code', 40);
    $table->string('location', 20);
    $table->string('colour', 20);
    $table->string('alias', 20);
    $table->string('image', 200);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// a fixtures table
Schema::create('fixtures', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('type', 20)->nullable();
    $table->string('date', 20)->nullable();
    $table->string('time', 20)->nullable();
    $table->string('venue', 20)->nullable();
    $table->string('address', 20)->nullable();
    $table->boolean('reminders')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

// a pivot table
Schema::create('clubs_fixtures', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('club_id')->unsigned(); // this is meant to be used as a foreign key
    $table->foreign('club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->integer('opponent_id')->unsigned(); // this is meant to be used as a foreign key
    $table->foreign('opponent_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->integer('fixture_id')->unsigned(); // this is meant to be used as a foreign key
    $table->foreign('fixture_id')->references('id')->on('fixtures')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So a CLUB can have MANY FIXTURES and a FIXTURE can have MANY CLUBS.
My Club model is as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Club extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'clubs';
    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }
    // set validation
    public static $createUpdateRules = array(
        'name'=>'required|min:2',
        'location'=>'required|min:2',
        'colour'=>'required|min:2',
        'alias'=>'required|min:2'
    );
    // We can define a many-to-many relation using the belongsToMany method:
    public function fixtures() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Fixture', 'clubs_fixtures')->withPivot('opponent_id');
    }
}
```

My Fixture model is as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Fixture extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'fixtures';
    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }
    // set validation
    public static $createRules = array(
        'type'=>'required|min:2',
        'opponent'=>'required|min:1',
        'date'=>'required|min:2',
        'time'=>'required|min:2',
        'venue'=>'required|min:2',
        'address'=>'required|min:2',
        'reminders'=>'required'
    );
}
```

Then in my controller I use Elequent ORM to get the upcoming fixtures

```
public function getViewClub($id) {
    $upcomingFixtures   = Club::find($id)->fixtures()->where('date', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->get();
    return View::make('club.view')->with('upcomingFixtures', $upcomingFixtures);
}

@foreach($upcomingFixtures as $upcomingFixture)
    <p>
        <a href="{{ URL::to('dashboard/'.$club->id.'/fixtures/upcoming/'.$upcomingFixture->id) }}">
            <strong>{{ $club->name }} vs Team Name</strong>
        </a>
    </p>
@endforeach
```

I hope I make sense with all this. I've tried to separate out the data, trying to keep the clean modular and dry, but I've immediately hit a problem here.
Hopefully a Laravel guru can steer me in the right direction here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, first you don't need to implement `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` (but keep it in User model ), second you can add relation clubs() inside your `Fixture` model

```
class Fixture extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'fixtures'; // you can also remove this line
    // set validation
    public static $createRules = array(
        'type'=>'required|min:2',
        //....
    );
    public function clubs() {
          return   $this->belongsToMany('Club','clubs_fixtures')
                   ->withPivot('opponent_id');
    }

}
```

Then in your controller

```
public function getViewClub($id) {
    $upcomingFixtures   = Fixture::with('clubs')
                    ->where('date', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->get();
    return View::make('club.view',compact('upcomingFixtures'));
}
@foreach($upcomingFixtures as $upcomingFixture)
   <h1>{{ $upcomingFixture->type }}</h1>
   @foreach($upcomingFixture->clubs as $club)
       <p>
          <a href="{{ URL::to('dashboard/'.$club->id.'/fixtures/upcoming/'.$upcomingFixture->id) }}">
            <strong>{{ $club->name }} vs Team Name</strong>
          </a>
       </p>
       <p> access to pivot table: {{ $club->pivot->opponent_id }}</p>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```